# boost::unique_lock/upgrade_to_unique_lock && boost::shared_lock can exist at the same time ? it worries me

Tags: boost, concurrency, locking, c++11

I did experiments with boost::upgrade_to_unique_lock/unique_lock && boost::shared_lock, scenario is:

- 1 write thread, where it has
  boost::unique_lock existing with a
  boost::shared_mutex, in the thread, I
  write to a global **AClass**
- 3 read thread, each one has
  boost::shared_lock with the same
  boost:;shrared_mutex, they have a
  loop to read the global **AClass**

I observed all the threads are holding locks( 1 unique, 3 shared ) at the same time, and they all 
running data access loops.

my concern is **AClass** is not thread-safe, if I can do read/write at the same time in different threads, the read could crash. Even it's not AClass, we use primitive types, reading them surely will not crash, but the data could be dirty, isn't it ?

Comment: Can you provide an example that exhibits the behavior you observe?

Comment: in my experient, AClass is std::string, in read thread, I print out the string, in write thread, I change string to the be the loop counter(i), I can see on screen, the string is changing constantly. I'm sure "they are holding the locks" is the lock objects are in the same scope as loop, just one line above the loop.

Comment: I think I found the problem, my own fault, in read thread, I used unamed lock, like this: boost::shared_lock< boost::shared_mutex>( gmutex ); now I change to boost::shared_lock< boost::shared_mutex> xx( gmutex ); it worked!

Comment: I have a tutorial on using shared_lock here:  http://home.roadrunner.com/~hinnant/mutexes/locking.html#Shared .  This link includes an implementation that is different than boost in the upgrade area.  I consider the boost implementation of the upgrade design inferior (documented at the link).  I do not yet know  if you are running into problems which my design would fix.  I'm posting in hopes of helping you and finding out where the confusion is.

Comment: This would be a good error to catch at compile time but I do not know how.

Answer (score 3):

```
boost::shared_lock<boost::shared_mutex>(gmutex);
```

This is not an "unnamed lock."  This creates a temporary `shared_lock` object which locks `gmutex`, then that temporary `shared_lock` object is destroyed, unlocking `gmutex`.  You need to name the object, making it a variable, for example:

```
boost::shared_lock<boost::shared_mutex> my_awesome_lock(gmutex);
```

`my_awesome_lock` will then be destroyed at the end of the block in which it is declared, which is the behavior you want.